# How do I create a simple query in SQL so that I can summarize a bartab?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where `Column 0` is filled with students' names, and `Column 1` is filled with how much money they owe a bar which shows as a positive amount (+), or how much they have paid the bar (a negative amount, -).  Multiple transactions by the same person means their names show up multiple times in the table.

Example below:

```
Amanda, +30
Bill, +250
Amanda, -30
Charles, +40
Charles, -40
Bill, -20
Bill, -15
```

How do I figure out where each student stands in terms of their bartab?  Here's my code.

```
SELECT  [COLUMN 0],   
        SUM ( [COLUMN 1] ),
FROM [Students].[dbo].bartabs GROUP BY [COLUMN 0];
```

I get an error

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'"

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra comma.

```
SELECT [COLUMN 0]   
      ,SUM ( [COLUMN 1] )  
  FROM [Students].[dbo].bartabs 
 GROUP BY [COLUMN 0]
```